# C comparison between -1 and 65535/4294967295/18446744073709551615

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I have a misunderstanding about the following statements:

```
printf("%d\n", -1 == 65535);
printf("%d\n", -1 == 4294967295UL);
printf("%d\n", -1 == 18446744073709551615);
printf("%d\n", -1 == 18446744073709551615UL);
```

The output is:

```
0
0
0
1
```

If if don't add the UL suffixes the compiler gives the following warning: `main.c:36:28: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned`

Can someone explain this to me please? Why for 18446744073709551615 the result is 0 but for 18446744073709551615UL the results is 1? It's ok not to add that suffix?

Thanks

Comment: It's converting `-1` to `unsigned long` to do the last comparison.

Comment: So it's ok not to add the UL suffix?

Comment: If you don't add the `UL` suffix it's a signed integer literal, and then it doesn't need to convert the negative number to unsigned.

Comment: @Barmar more like "If you don't add the **U** suffix it's a signed integer **constant** ..."

Comment: GCC is lying. Its error message says it is giving `18446744073709551615` an unsigned type, but [using `_Generic` shows the type is `__int128_t`](https://godbolt.org/z/f4M3MfhWj), which is signed.

Comment: Robert Ilin, to be clear the `L`  in the large constants is irrelevant to the question.  Your issues applies because of the `u` or `U`, not `L`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good investigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 3 exhibits a bug in GCC.

In GCC 11.2 for x86_64, the signed and unsigned `int` types are 32 bits, the signed and unsigned `long` and `long long` types are 64 bits, and there are also extended types `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` with width 128.

In `-1 == 65535`, `-1` and `65535` are both `int`. They are unequal, so the comparison produces 0.

In `-1 == 4294967295UL`, `-1` is an `int`, and `4294967295UL` is an `unsigned long`. Per the usual arithmetic conversions, −1 is converted to `unsigned long`, which wraps modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, producing 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. That does not equal 4,294,967,295, so the comparison produces 0.

In `-1 == 18446744073709551615`, `18446744073709551615` is too large for the normal types. C 2018 6.4.4.1 5 says the type of an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is the first of `int`, `long int`, or `long long int` that can represent it. Since none of those can represent it in this C implementation, paragraph 6 applies:

> If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list, it may have an extended integer type, if the extended integer type can represent its value. If all of the types in the list for the constant are signed, the extended integer type shall be signed…

From this, we see the type of `18446744073709551615` should be `__int128_t`. This is confirmed by using `_Generic` to reveal the type; [the following program prints “__int128_t”](https://godbolt.org/z/KaWsbMn9K):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", _Generic(18446744073709551615,
            __int128_t: "__int128_t",
            default:    "something else")
        );
}
```

In contrast, Clang 13.0.0 uses `unsigned long long`.](https://godbolt.org/z/a5Y3h5Wbo)

Thus, GCC’s error message that states “integer constant is so large that it is unsigned” is incorrect. GCC uses a different type than its error message states, so this is a bug in GCC.

Given that the type is `__int128_t`, −1 and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 are both representable in the type, so evaluation of the expression converts −1 to `__int128_t` with no change in value, the values are unequal, and the comparison produces 0.

(Since Clang uses `unsigned long long`, it produces 1.)

For confirmation, we see that `printf("%d\n", -18446744073709551615 < 0);` prints [“1” in GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/c8nGMr4KT), showing the comparison was performed with a signed type, whereas [Clang prints “0”](https://godbolt.org/z/nznxMr7oG).

Finally, in `-1 == 18446744073709551615UL`, the usual arithmetic conversions convert −1 to `unsigned long`, which wraps modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, producing 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. Then the two operands are equal, and the comparison produces 1.

Comment: Nice use of `_Generic()` :) Note that **gcc** does not exactly use 128 bit arithmetics as `printf("%d\n", 18446744073709551615 == 36893488147419103231)` outputs `1`.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. But I still have some questions. I have the following statements:
`unsigned long a = 9223372036854775808UL;
 signed long b = -9223372036854775808;
 printf("%d", a == b);`

My questions are:
1. Why do I get the following warning `warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned` since signed long can hold value -9223372036854775808?
2. Why it outputs value 1 (TRUE) since they're not equal? Is the signed variable converted to unsigned? Is there any way to compare one signed long variable and one unsigned long variable and the result to be correct?

Comment: @RobertIlin: 1. In C, there are no negative constants. `-9223372036854775808` is the negation operator `-` and the constant `9223372036854775808`. The compiler has to parse `9223372036854775808` when translating the program, and the negation is conceptually applied when the program executes. So, since `9223372036854775808` is not representable in a 64-bit `signed long`, the compiler complains. 2. When an `unsigned long` is compared to a `signed long`, the `signed long` is converted to `unsigned long` before the comparison.

Comment: @RobertIlin: C does not provide any way to directly compare the value of a signed type to the value of an unsigned type. Comparisons only operate on operands of one type. If there is a larger signed type that can hold all the values of the signed type and all the values of the unsigned type, you can convert both operands to that type and compare them. Otherwise, you need to write your own code to do the comparison…

Comment: … For example, `b < 0 || b < a` will test whether signed `b` is less than unsigned `a` (of the same width) because either `b` is less than 0 and so is less than any unsigned `a` or `b` is non-negative and so the conversion to unsigned will not change it, so the `b < a` will provide the desired result. For comparing for equality, we can use `0 <= b && b == a`.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the warning, it seems that if I add the `U` suffix the warning is gone - is this correct. Also, I saw on Wikipedia that the range for `signed long long` starts from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,807` and not from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` and I was wondering why so.

Comment: @RobertIlin: Re “is this correct”: Sure. Re “I saw on Wikipedia”: When referring to other sources, give complete citations, such as links to web pages and the specific position in them. Re “the range for `signed long long`”: There is no single range for `signed long long`. The C standard requires that a C’s implementation for `signed long long` be able to represent **at least** from −9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807, but it may be more…

Comment: … The reason for starting that requirement at −(2^63−1) instead of −(2^63) is because the standard still allows representing negative numbers using one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude instead of two’s complement.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how integer constants are treated.

For decimal constants with no suffix, the compiler checks the value to see if it will fit into the following types, in this order:

- `int`
- `long int`
- `long long int`

The compiler gives you a warning because the value 18446744073709551615 will not fit into any of those types.  What happens next is dictated by section 6.4.4.1p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If an integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list,
> it may have an extended integer type, if the extended integer type can
> represent its value. If all of the types in the list for the constant
> are signed, the extended integer type shall be signed. If all of the
> types in the list for the constant are unsigned, the extended integer
> type shall be unsigned. If the list contains both signed and unsigned
> types, the extended integer type may be signed or unsigned. If an
> integer constant cannot be represented by any type in its list and has
> no extended integer type, then the integer constant has no type

And since 18446744073709551615 doesn't fit into one of the above types, the compiler will attempt to fit the value into a signed extended type if one exists.  GCC in particular supports a type called `__int128` , so assuming you're using GCC then the constant has that type.

Then for the comparison `-1 == 18446744073709551615`, the left side of the comparison is converted to type `__int128` which it can do without a change of value, and the result is false.

In the case of the constant `18446744073709551615UL`, the suffix gives it type `unsigned long` and the value does fit into that type.  Then for the comparison `-1 == 18446744073709551615UL`, `-1` is converted to type `unsigned long`.  By the rules of converting an out-of-range signed type to an unsigned type, the `int` value `-1` is converted to the `unsigned long` value 18446744073709551615 and the comparison is true.

The warning generated by gcc is misleading in that it suggests that the constant is unsigned when it actually is not.  This may be a reference to C89 behavior where this constant would in fact have type `unsigned long`.   If the `-std=c89` flag is passed to gcc, you'll get another warning in addition to the first:  `warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90`.  The results will also differ because of this, with the third call to `printf` outputting 1.

Comment: What you are describing is inconsistent with the error message `main.c:36:28: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned`. Indeed **clang** produces  a similar warning `integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned` but the output is consistent with `18446744073709551615` being interpreted as `18446744073709551615U`, namely `0 0 1 1`.

Comment: @chqrlie Look again.  OP is getting "0" for the third statement. C89 mode will generate the output you got, while C99 or C11 mode generates OP's output.

Comment: See my comment on the question: GCC is lying in its error message.

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on the type the compiler selects for integer constants.

If an integer decimal constant does not have a suffix then the compiler considers the following types to represent a constant: `int`, `long int`. `long long int`.

This value `18446744073709551615` is a maximum value that can be stored in an object of the type `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`. It can not be represented as having the type `signed long int` or `signed long long int`.

When a constant is specified with a suffix `ul` or `UL` the compiler considers sequentially the types `unsigned long int` and `unsigned long long int` and selects the first type an object of which can represent the constant.

So in this expression

```
-1 == 18446744073709551615UL
```

the right operand of the comparison has the maximum value represented in the corresponding unsigned integer type selected by the compiler and the left operand is converted to this type by promoting the sign bit due to the usual arithmetic conversions. As a result `-1` is represented as the maximum unsigned value stored in the selected unsigned integer type.

By the way it seems that in the used by you system `sizeof( unsigned long )` is equal to `sizeof( unsigned long long )`. Otherwise if `sizeof( unsigned long )` would be equal to `sizeof( unsigned int )` (as it is in Windows) then this call

```
printf("%d\n", -1 == 4294967295UL);
```

also outputted `1`.

Comment: "It can not be represented as having the type `signed long int`" --> at least not until `long long` is 128-bit - hmm, about 10 years I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an example of inconsistent behavior of the compiler leading to surprising results:

- `printf("%d\n", -1 == 18446744073709551615);` compiled with **gcc** produces a warning `integer constant is so large that it is unsigned` because it exceeds the range of type `long long int`. If you were to store this number into an `unsigned long long`, you would probably get the expected unsigned long long value, but it is used in a test and you are comparing `-1` with a positive integer of an extended type, so the compiler might just optimize the test as false in all cases. **gcc** outputs `1` for `printf("%d\n", 18446744073709551615 == 36893488147419103231)` so the compiler does not exactly use 128 bit arithmetics to evaluate this test.
- compiling with **clang** produces a similar warning `integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned` but the code generated is different and the output is `1`, meaning that `18446744073709551615` is typed as `unsigned long long` internally, consistently with the comment emitted.

Here is a program to substantiate my statement:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define typeof(X)  _Generic((X),                                        \
                   long double: "long double",                          \
                   double: "double",                                    \
                   float: "float",                                      \
                   unsigned long long int: "unsigned long long int",    \
                   long long int: "long long int",                      \
                   unsigned long int: "unsigned long int",              \
                   long int: "long int",                                \
                   unsigned int: "unsigned int",                        \
                   int: "int",                                          \
                   unsigned short: "unsigned short",                    \
                   short: "short",                                      \
                   unsigned char: "unsigned char",                      \
                   signed char: "signed char",                          \
                   char: "char",                                        \
                   bool: "bool",                                        \
                   default: "other")

int main() {
#define TEST(x)  printf("%8s has type %s and size %zu\n", #x, typeof(x), sizeof(x))
    TEST(9223372036854775807);
    TEST(18446744073709551615U);
    TEST(18446744073709551615);
}
```

Output with **clang**:

```
typeof.c:27:10: warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned
      [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]
    TEST(18446744073709551615);
         ^
typeof.c:27:10: warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed integer type, interpreting as unsigned
      [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]
2 warnings generated.

9223372036854775807 has type long int and size 8
18446744073709551615U has type unsigned long int and size 8
18446744073709551615 has type unsigned long long int and size 8
```

Output with **gcc**:

```
typeof.c: In function `main':
typeof.c:27:30: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
     TEST(18446744073709551615);
                              ^
typeof.c:27:30: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
9223372036854775807 has type long int and size 8
18446744073709551615U has type unsigned long int and size 8
18446744073709551615 has type other and size 16
```

Comment: See my comment on the question: GCC is lying in its error message.

Comment: It's not UB.  C89 allows for an unsuffixed decimal to have type `unsigned long`.  Try compiling with `-std=c89` vs `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree. See my `typeof` program that proves it.